# Cisco 2960 radius configuration

Tags: cisco, network, authentication, radius, aaa

I have multiple cisco switches like `Nexus` family and `IOS` family switches and now i am trying to configure centralized authentication so i have install Freeradius and freeIPA (ldap server)

I have created two group `net-admin` and `net-operator` (read-only view) in LDAP and map then in freeradius in file `/etc/raddb/user`

```
# Cisco ldap group def:
#
DEFAULT  ldap1-Ldap-Group == "cn=net-admin,cn=groups,cn=compat,dc=example,dc=com"
         Service-Type = Administrative-User,
         Service-Type = Login-User,
         Service-Type = NAS-Prompt-User,
         Cisco-AVPair = "shell:roles=network-admin",
         Cisco-AVPair += "shell:priv-lvl=15"

DEFAULT  ldap1-Ldap-Group == "cn=net-operator,cn=groups,cn=compat,dc=example,dc=com"
         Service-Type = Administrative-User,
         Service-Type = Login-User,
         Service-Type = NAS-Prompt-User,
         Cisco-AVPair = "shell:roles=net-operator",
         Cisco-AVPair += "shell:priv-lvl=1"
```

Configured all cisco nexus switches aaa for radius and everything working great!

now comes to `Cisco 2960` switches which is behaving very odd, I have configured following.

```
aaa new-model
!
!
aaa authentication login default group radius local
aaa authorization exec default local
aaa authorization network default local
!
radius-server host 10.10.10.25 auth-port 1812 acct-port 1813 key Secret123
```

When i try to login on cisco 2960 switch it failed so i have create just local account to see if it works or not so i did following

`2960(config)# username spatel password foo`

now i am able to login on cisco 2960 switch using my LDAP password not `foo` so question is why Cisco 2960 not looking into LDAP account instead looking at local ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
aaa authorization exec default local
```

Doesn't allow you to start a shell (Exec) with Radius credentials.
You should change it to:

```
aaa authorization exec default group radius local
```

Comment: Nice! it works but now my users directly get `#` exec shell, how do i make them have limited privilege like only `read-only` or `show` only?

Comment: You need command authorization for that.  TACACS is a better fit to do that kind of control.

Comment: can't we define privileges on cisco switch and map `priv-lvl` in radius?

Comment: nevermind, its working now, i am able to map privileges, my problem was i specified multiple `Service-Type` in radius and that was the issue. after removing them it works